# How to unset elements in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a zend form in which I have many elements. I use form on many places. I have an element of `file` and that is:

```
$file= new Zend_Form_Element_File('merchantLogo');
        $file->setDestination("application_data/merchant/logo/original/");
        $file->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
        $file->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif,jpeg');
        $file->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

Now What I want to ask that how can I unset any element of this zend form. I want this because although on my one action I am not using this element, but this element is creating problem. 
So how to unset any element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `Zend_Form::removeElement()`. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.methods

Example

```
$form->removeElement('merchantLogo');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is quiete easy:

```
$this->removeElement('merchantLogo');
```

The public function removeElement() on the Zend_Form takes the name of an element and removes it from the form.

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.methods

Answer (score 3):

1:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('test');
if ($condition) {
    $form->addElement($element);
}
```

2:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('test');
$form->addElement($element);
if (!$condition) {
    $form->removeElement('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$form = $form->remove('merchantLogo'); // or chain to remove ->('anotherElement');`

Newbie note:

Replace `$form` with the return value of `remove(')` method to use the updated form.